# Duplication of Mediators in Robotlegs AS3 MVCS

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, robotlegs

I'm using robot legs framework and wondering how mediator.mapView works with multiple instances of the same view. For example, in the following, is a new ItemDisplayMediator created for every ItemDisplay instantiated, or do all ItemDisplay's use the same mediator? If they each instantiate a new mediator, is it possible to use a single mediator for multiples of the same class/view?

```
mediatorMap.mapView(ItemDisplay, ItemDisplayMediator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each view instance is mediated by a different Mediator instance.

If you want a single mediator for multiple items, then create a Mediator for a container and mediate its children.

Comment: Makes sense. Someone mentioned to me "using interfaces for preventing the duplications of views" (I'm guessing he meant using something similar to RL's mapSingletonOf for a view though) ...not sure if that's a reality.

Comment: Yeah, I'm really not sure what he was talking about! I just tried mapping your mediator as a singleton as well as to a view... but RobotLegs ignored the singleton mapping.

Answer (score 1):

alecmce is correct, the MediatorMap is going to apply a new instance of the mediator to each instance of the view that is being mediated comes onto the stage. A mediator, as it is written in robotlegs, is only equipped to handle a single view component at any given time. The actual mediator isn't injected anywhere, so it isn't mapped with the injector.